# Piping with multiple commands

Tags: linux, bash, unix, pipe

Assume you have a file called “heading” as follows

```
echo "Permissions^V<TAB>^V<TAB>Size^V<TAB>^V<TAB>File Name" > heading

echo "-------------------------------------------------------" >> heading
```

Write a (single) set of commands that will create a report as follows:
make a list of the names, permissions and size of all the files in your current directory,
matching (roughly) the format of the heading you just created,
put the list of files directly following the heading, and
save it all into a file called “file.list”.
All this is to be done without destroying the heading file.

I need to be able to do this all in a pipleline without altering the file. I can't seem to do this without destroying the file. Can somebody please make a pipe for me?

Comment: The `>> heading` appends the output to the `heading` file; you need to save all to a file called `file.list` so presumably your command needs to end with `>> file.list` at some point. You only show how the heading is created. How did you try to tackle the rest?

Comment: how about something like `ls -l  | awk '{print $1 "         " $5 "          " $9}'` assuming permissions doesn't include owner/group.

Comment: i tried ls -l | sed  ‘s/:/^V<tab>^V<tab>/g’ | >> heading > file.list

Answer (score 1):

You can use command group:

```
{ cat heading; ls -l | sed 's/:/^V<tab>^V<tab>/g'; } > file.list
```